# C - Formatting String size with special characters

Tags: c, string, format, special-characters

So, I was trying to print fixtures from a competition with strings well formatted but i found out that whenever there is a special character like **'é'** or **'í'** or **'á'** it would print +1 size even though i specified the max length.

Where is the code:

```
printf("=> %-25s (%d) vs (%d) \t%-25s\n", f->home_team_name, f->goals_home_team, f->goals_away_team, f->away_team_name);
```

For teams with those characters the output is like:

```
=> Palmeiras               (2) vs (0)   Botafogo               
=> Atlético Mineiro       (4) vs (3)    Grémio                
=> Atlético PR            (3) vs (0)    Palmeiras              
=> Botafogo                (2) vs (2)   Cruzeiro
```

But i want the output to look like, even with special characters:

```
=> Tottenham Hotspur FC    (0) vs (0)   Leicester City FC      
=> West Ham United FC      (0) vs (0)   Everton FC             
=> Burnley FC              (0) vs (0)   AFC Bournemouth
```

I've tried to look for formatting flags but can't find the solution.

Comment: Post the code that set `home_team_name` to `"Atlético Mineiro"`.

Comment: I'm using Curl to get that from an url (http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/444/teams) and then using jsonlib to convert that into the string.

Comment: Is the `home_team_name` encoded in UTF-8? Remember that UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding scheme, and that some characters may use two or more bytes. These are probably counted by the (generally) UTF-8 unaware `printf` function.

Comment: "even though i specified the max length." is not coded here.  The 25 in `"%-25s"` is the _minimum_ width.

Comment: Yes it is in UTF-8

Comment: C and UTF still has a way to go.  I suspect the solution may include  `wprintf()`

Comment: The special characters count as 2 therefore it adds 1 less space so it looks strange in the output. I guess thats it?

Comment: Well, `printf` counts bytes, but your console interprets the characters as UTF-8, which encodes codepoints with variable lengths, so the two disagree on what the length of the string is.

Comment: @chriptus13 The link is not a sufficient substitute for showing how your code assigns `home_team_name`.  Posting code that compiles and replicates the problem will net better answers.

Comment: @chux i've tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @chriptus13 "i've tried" is unclear as to what you have tried.  "it doesn't work" is not clear on what or how something does not work.  Post your compilable code and inputs used.

Answer (score 3):

The format string in `printf` does not take multibyte characters into account.

A possible solution is to count *wide characters* of a string by [`mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) function. The obtained count is then subtracted from the length (i.e. in bytes) of the examined string. This yields a (nonnegative) "compensation value", that may be added to `printf`'s format field width.

The `mbstowcs` function is described as:

> Converts a multibyte character string from the array whose first
>   element is pointed to by `src` to its wide character representation.
>   Converted characters are stored in the successive elements of the
>   array pointed to by `dst`. No more than `len` wide characters are written
>   to the destination array.

In your case, this means that UTF-8 encoded octets (represented within array of `char`) are converted into *some* wide representation, that guarantees that any multibyte character (up to locale-specific [`MB_CUR_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) bytes) can be encoded by no more than one `wchar_t` object.

The relevant quote from C11 Standard is contained in 7.19/2 *Common definitions `<stddef.h>`*:

> `wchar_t`
>
> which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct
>   codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified
>   among the supported locales;

For instance, on Linux platform, wide characters are most likely to be represented in [UCS-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) (known as UTF-32).

Here is a proof of concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

static inline size_t widestrlen(const char *str)
{
    return mbstowcs(NULL, str, strlen(str));
}

static inline size_t compensation(const char *str)
{
    return strlen(str) - widestrlen(str);
}

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    // Print some debugging information regarding selected locale
    printf("Current locale for LC_TYPE category: %s\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL));
    printf("Maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character: %zu\n", MB_CUR_MAX);
    printf("Does current encoding support shift states? : %s\n\n", mblen(NULL, 0) ? "Yes" : "No");

    int goals_home_teams[] = { 4, 0 };
    int goals_away_teams[] = { 3, 0 };
    const char *home_team_names[] = { "Atlético Mineiro", "West Ham United FC" };
    const char *away_team_names[] = { "Grémio", "Everton FC" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("=> %-*s (%d) vs (%d) \t%-*s\n",
            25 + (int) compensation(home_team_names[i]),
            home_team_names[i], goals_home_teams[i], goals_away_teams[i],
            25 + (int) compensation(away_team_names[i]),
            away_team_names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Current locale for LC_TYPE category: en_US.UTF-8
Maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character: 6
Does current encoding support shift states? : No

=> Atlético Mineiro          (4) vs (3)     Grémio                   
=> West Ham United FC        (0) vs (0)     Everton FC
```

Comment: Ya i've thought about that but didn't want to make this with a big thing so just trying to figure out if there's a way of avoiding that!

Comment: I came up with an almost identical solution. This however doesn't work for asian characters that can be multiple cursor positions wide. `mbstowcs()` counts each Kanji character for 1 while in fact it is very often 2 for alignment purposes. Any solution to that?